# Recursive remove directory using SFTP

Tags: python, console, sftp

I use SFTP server for making database backup and all web site with it structure. I use bad script and now I make double duplicates on my SFTP server. I use `rmdir folder` but I get error:

```
Couldn't remove directory: Failure
```

If I understand right in SFTP I can remove directory just if it empty. And if I use `rm folder/*` I don't remove inner folders.

How I can doit another way?

Comment: I use Filezilla for this.

Comment: I can connect to it only from hosting VPS server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement simple solution in python. I think it somebody help in future

```
import os
import paramiko
from stat import S_ISDIR

server ="any.sftpserver"
username = "uname"
password = "***"
path_to_hosts_file = os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(path_to_hosts_file))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)

def isdir(path):
    try:
        return S_ISDIR(sftp.stat(path).st_mode)
    except IOError:
        return False

def rm(path):
    files = sftp.listdir(path=path)

    for f in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, f)
        if isdir(filepath):
            rm(filepath)
        else:
            sftp.remove(filepath)

    sftp.rmdir(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rm("/path/to/some/directory/to/remove")
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also mount your remote directory with

```
sshfs user@yourdomain.com:/path/to/remote local/path
```

then just `cd local/path` and then you are free to use `rm -r folder`

Answer (score 9):

itdxer's solution is very nice, but it doesn't delete everything: it only deletes a subfolder if it was empty to start with, otherwise it will only delete its contents. It is also possible to make it shorter by combining isdir and rm.

```
def rm(path):
    files = sftp.listdir(path)

    for f in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, f)
        try:
            sftp.remove(filepath)
        except IOError:
            rm(filepath)

    sftp.rmdir(path)
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The only drawback is that `os.path.join()` may not generate correct paths cross-systems. Running this script in Windows against a Linux server, paths such as `/tmp/dev\\afile.txt` were generated, crashing the script. I ended up using `'/'.join(...)` which is not universally correct but OK when the target system is Linux

Comment: you could also use `posixpath.join()` for linux servers

Comment: Why use try/except here though? Wouldn't it be better to explicitly check if its a file or directory? If there would be many directories, wouldn't it hit to performance, needing to catch many exceptions?

Comment: @Andrius a bit late, but here's the answer for your question. In Python it's usually [better to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/). Performance related to exceptions is usually not a big deal comparing to real bottlenecks like network I/O. Or in other words ["premature optimization really the root of all evil"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/168063).

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov yeah, I know about Python recommending EAFP. Though I use this rule of thumb. If I expect most calls to pass, I catch exceptions. But if I know that lots of the time exception might occur, then I check it, instead of catching. For example if 50% of the cases exception is expected to occur, I use simple check. Is it still recommended to use try/except if most of the time exception will occur, instead of it passing?

Comment: @Andrius Consider following argument: if we use `not is_dir()` and then `remove()` we send two requests to a remote SFTP instead of a single request on successful deletion (and if it's a dir we have equal number of requests for both approaches). What may potentially be even more important, is that EAFP approach allows us to delete file atomically: there's no headache about third-party will change something between we do `is_dir()` and `remove()`. We should be pragmatic in each specific situation, but in this one personally I would prefer EAFP for the reasons above alone.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov I agree that in this case EAFP could be good choice.